# How to use google adsense (or similar) for a web app with user specific content

Tags: advertising, google-adsense

I am working on a site that allows users to log in and enter their own information.  Each user will have their own login, and enter their own content that can only be seen by them.  It is conceptually similar to a to-do list site like Remember The Milk.

I would like to use Google Adsense as a way of getting revenue from it, but from what I have read so far it has no way of handling this kind of site.  What I would want from a service like Adsense is a way to submit a set of keywords that I can extract from the user's text, and get back a set of adverts to display to the user.  There is Adsense's search facility but that has to be submitted by the user themselves - I expect if the server submitted search requests automatically it would be a fast track to getting banned from Adsense.

Is there any way to do what I want using Adsense, or are there any competing ad services that will do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Look into DKI adsense. That might give you a clue.

You can try to write a script that will pull the user input from your database, sort it for common words and then modify the keyword list on adsense yourself every week to keep ads relevant.  That's if adsense doesn't already have something to accommodate dynamic content-keyword changes.  HTH